# How can I write a recursive function to get an array representing the set of every permutation of values?

Tags: javascript, recursion, set

I want to write a function -- call it `setGenerator()` -- that accepts two parameters:

1. An array of possible values
2. An integer maximum

I want my function to return an array of arrays, representing every possible permutation of the possible values, from sets of size 0 up to sets of the specified maximum.

So no matter what, this function would always at least return an array containing an empty array. But here's a quick example to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
setGenerator(["A", "B", "C"], 2);
// should return:
// [ [], ["A"], ["B"], ["C"], ["A", "A"], ["A", "B"], ["A", "C"], 
// ["B", "A"], ["B", "B"], ["B", "C"], ["C", "A"], ["C", "B"], ["C", "C"] ]
```

Look at the input and output here in my example. The input says my possible values are the strings A, B, and C, and that I should form sets of size 0 through 2. So the resultant sets returned are:

- A set of size zero []
- Sets of size one for each possible value: [A], [B], [C]
- Sets of size two for every permutation: [A,A], [A,B], [A,C], [B,A], etc.

If I were to have set my maximum to 3, though, then the function should also return all permutation sets of length 3.

I hope that makes sense. Can anyone help me write this in JavaScript? It would have to involve recursion, but I'm getting stuck when thinking about it.

**UPDATE:** If you read the comments, you'll see that what I'm describing here are not technically permutations. This is actually a much larger set than just permutations. But hopefully the target I'm shooting for here is made clear by my example above. These can perhaps be called **permutations with repetition**. I think there should be x factorial of them for a given number, but keep in mind I'm asking about all numbers 0 up to x.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework. What did you try.

Comment: It's not homework... I've been out of school for 10 years, hence a little rusty! :)

Comment: Why ["A","A"], ["B","B"], ["C","C"] are permutations?

Comment: What do you mean why? They are!

Comment: Type: `[javascript] [permutation]` into the search box.

Comment: I don't think they are. if the input is ["A","A","B"], then ["A","A"] would be a permutation.

Comment: plbsam, well please don't concern yourself too much with the word choice; I think my point gets across regardless of what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: And yes, you're absolutely right that [A,A] would be a permutation!

Comment: I was concerning the word choice because, your definition makes the problem more complex.. :)

Comment: Hence why I'm asking for help. :)

Comment: Okay, so I am realizing that these can't technically be called permutations, because nPr(3,2) = 6, but the number of possible "perminationevers" (permutations/combinations/whatevers) for three values limited to 2 at a time is 9. So epascarello, Googling for JavaScript permutations won't help you here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gave it a try because the problem was interesting..

```
var results = [];

var setGenerator = function(values,max,prefix){
    prefix = typeof prefix !== 'undefined' ? prefix : []; 
    results.push(prefix);
    for (var i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
        var newPrefix = prefix.slice(0);
        newPrefix.push(values[i]);
        if (newPrefix.length <= max)
            setGenerator(values, max, newPrefix);
    }   
};

setGenerator(["A","B","C"],2);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Wow, I like this approach better than the one I came up with. And most of all, I like that you found the problem interesting and attempted a solution. That, to me, represents the best spirit of what StackOverflow is about. In contrast, people who are quick to make unhelpful comments like "we're not here to do your homework" represent the worst of StackOverflow. So your answer here is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
function addPermutationsWithRepetition(aFinalSet, aAllowed, iLength, aTemp) {
    if (typeof aTemp != 'object') {
        aTemp = [];
    }
    if ( aTemp.length >= iLength ) {
        aFinalSet.push(aTemp);
    } else {
        for (var j = 0; j < aAllowed.length; j++) {
            var aTemp2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(aTemp));
            aTemp2.push(aAllowed[j]);
            addPermutationsWithRepetition(aFinalSet, aAllowed, iLength, aTemp2);
        });
    }
}
```

Then I just have to do this:

```
var aFinalSet = [];
for (var i = 0; i < iMaximum; i++) {
    addPermutationsWithRepetition(aFinalSet, aAllowed, i);
}
```